# Calendar not starting from today jqueryui daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using the jQuery UI Daterangepicker ([reference](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/)).

I want the calendar to start from today, with no max date. I am trying to use moment in the calendar for the dates.

This is the HTML & JS code I have but it sets the end date on today with no minDate.

```
<input id="search-vac-daterange" name="search-vac-daterange">

$("#search-vac-daterange").daterangepicker({
    minDate: moment(),
    startDate: moment()
});
```

I have also tried with **minDate: new Date()** and **startDate: new Date()**. No results either. The dates stay with today as end date.

NOTE: moment is working because a console.log(moment()); returns me a moment object:

```
p {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: j, _d: Fri Jan 18 2019 16:14:35 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd), …}
```

***EDIT: I have tried the suggestions as given below, none of them have an impact on the solution.***

```
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
minDate: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
startDate: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
```

or

```
minDate: new Date(moment("11-02-1993").format("YYYY-MM-DD")),
startDate: new Date(moment("11-02-1994").format("YYYY-MM-DD")),
```

Added image to show the problem:
[image: jquery ui calednar problemn start date]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues. Firstly `moment()` returns a Moment object which is not a valid value for the `minDate` or `startDate` properties of the picker. To fix this just pass a standard Date object.

Secondly you need to provide options to the underlying jQueryUI datepicker control  within the `datepickerOptions` object:

```js
$("#search-vac-daterange").daterangepicker({
  datepickerOptions: {
    minDate: new Date(),
    startDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: '+1y' // required for future dates to be selectable
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.3.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<input id="search-vac-daterange" name="search-vac-daterange">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was thinking the same thing, hence why I already tried using new Date() , but it does not work.

Comment: I edited my post after trying your suggestions. I still cannot get it working. It seems like it does not pick up the min & startDate at all. Even though the change event listener, presetRanges and applybuttonText are working.

Comment: I re-read the documentation; you need to provide the properties to the underlying jQueryUI datepicker in a separate object. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: I've also just edited a working snippet in to the question to give you a demo. As an aside, if you want to disable past dates you should look in to removing the text labels on the left as most of them will fail your validation

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working. I could not get the moment version working, i guess it has to do with formatting. But with the new Date() it works fine! Thanks a lot !